# Loop through HTML content and return values as global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if it is possible to create `var`s in JavaScript dynamically and return them into a global variables. Example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <span class="span_1">content</span>
  <span class="span_2">another</span>
  <span class="span_3">yup content</span>
</div>
```

and following function:

```
function getContent() {
  var divs = $('#parent').children('span').length;
  for(var i = 1; i < divs; i++) {
    jQuery('.span_'+i).html(); //this returned as global variables for each span
  }
}
```

as you can see I want to loop through the spans HTML and want to have variables with content of each span as global variables. How would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `var divs = $('#parent div').length` it is `0` and you dont have any span with class name of `span_0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map()` this way:

```
var globalVar; // javascript set the value as "undefined".
```

Then in your function do this:

```
function getContent() {
     globalVar = $('#parent span').map(function(){
                     return $(this).text();
                 }).get();

   //results in --> globalVar = ["content", "another", "yup content"]

}
```

`.map()` creates an array with the collection of your selectors and make sure to chain it with `.get()` to get the collection in the array.

Comment: and `globalVar` is an array then?

Comment: @supersize globalVar is a variable and with use of `.map().get()` returns the values as an array. so this global var holds array.

Comment: thank you, that works! Just to mention, you mixed up two letters in the variable of getContent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get an array having the content of span elements using jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) method as shown below:

```js
var spanContents = $("#parent span").map(function(i, elm) {
  return $(elm).text(); // or html() if applicable
}).get();
console.log(spanContents);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span class="span_1">content</span>
  <span class="span_2">another</span>
  <span class="span_3">yup content</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as iterating through that loop (that should start in 1 like Jai said), you can use ["Attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

For example:

`$('#parent span[class^="span_"])`

will return an array with each span having class beginning with 'span_' inside your #parent element.